# Trying to hide/show div dx-field class

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular7

I am trying to hide/show the div class dx-field below is the syntax I am using to set the visibility

```
 <div class="dx-field" ng-style="{'visibility': isShow?'visible':'hidden'}">
  <div class="dx-field-label">.....</div>
  <dx-select-box .....></dx-select-box>
 </div>
```

But no matter what is the boolean value the div class shows up. How can I hide/show the div class dx-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Angular 7 you have to change `ng-style` to be `[ngStyle]`